# Autoclick a form input?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an adhoc code that save me pressing a repetitive button on a webpage, I opened F12 developer and tried using getElementbyID(..).click(); however didn't quite work, this is part extract of the button, I wonder if someone can advise what code I can use to automatically submit the button? Any help will be greatly appreicated. Best regards, Jon

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the tour to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: [JavaScript is NOT JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: `document.getElementById("existing_Unique_ID_of_a_button").click()`

Comment: you need to use jquery

Comment: @HamzaNig No he does not

Comment: @mplungjan yeah but jquery its better than solo javascript

Comment: @mplungjan but your right even javascript it work

Comment: @HamzaNig Please don't be this guy: https://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: @CodeF0x your right (i see your profile ) and i anderstand :)

Comment: @HamzaNig Please don't get me wrong, jQuery may be cool (I'm not using it) and stuff, but for just one single task any framework would be too much. Have a great day :).

Answer (score 1):

> what code I can use to automatically submit the button

If this is for a regular form post without AJAX then you can select the form then use `submit()`.

E.g.

```js
/* 
 * The variable myform is previously determined such as by `document.forms[0]`
 * or a similar DOM selector method
 */
myform.submit();
```

If this is for a non-form button then use the `click()` method as suggested in the comments above. However, be aware that for this method there would have to be an Event Listener attached for the button to do anything of value.